# why my computer shutdown everytime when running hand detection.launch

Tags: ros, kinect, shutdown

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the mit-ros-pkg and everytime I roslaunch the hand detection.launch using kinect, after a while, my computer will be shutdown automatically...help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33295/why-my-computer-shutdown-everytime-when-running-hand-detection.launch/) by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2317/tan/) on 2012-05-09**:
Thank you very much. You are right the reason is my computer getting too warm as it was very hot in my lab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I actually think that's not a problem with the hand detector but with your computer. Is guess the hand detector is using a lot of CPU. Is your computer maybe getting too warm?

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-07**:
+1 on this analysis. Bad CPU / RAM can also manifest as random crashes under heavy load; maybe you should run memtest.